# How to create and execute unit test cases for Xamarin.forms Android project like all the methods defined in MainActivity.cs class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

As per requirement, we need to write unit test cases in our Xamarin.Forms project. We want to do unit testing for Android and iOS projects as well. For example - creating and executing unit test cases for `MainActivity.cs` and `AppDelegate.cs` methods.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is unfortunately too broad for answering here. If you already tried something, please tell us about it and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Platform specific code, such as Android activities, fragments, etc. cannot be unit tested the same way that a .NET Standard library can. It is application code and it needs to be executed on a device. There are frameworks that allow you to write UI tests that will test the platform specific code.

Check out [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/) on coded UI test frameworks.

A good practice is to move all business logic into a shared library, which can be easily unit testable, and use a UI testing framework to test the application itself.